# Returning a variable isn't working in Python

Tags: python

I have to do a Python NEA, but it doesn't count towards my GCSE grade for some reason, and every time the function repeats the variables `score1` and `score2` reset to `0`, when I want them to keep their values which is added to inside the procedure.

Here's roughly what the code that doesn't work looks like (I'm not allowed to bring the code home but I am allowed to use the internet for help so this should be fine):

```
import random

def roll(score1, score2):
    roll1 = random.randint(1,6)
    score1 += roll1
    roll2 = random.randint(1,6)
    score2 += roll2
    print(score1, score2)
    print('---')
    return score1, score2

for __ in range(3):
    score1 = score2 = 0
    for __ in range(4):
         roll(score1, score2)
```

Comment: `while` instead of `While`. `def` instead of `Def` and so on. Python is case-sensitive

Comment: @roganjosh that's not the problem, I sent this on my phone and didn't change autocorrect, that's my bad.

Comment: Please post a proper [mcve], not just some code that vaguely looks like your real code and doesn't illustrate the problem. You only ever set `score1` and `score2` to 0, so I'm not sure what you mean by "reset".

Comment: Sorry, I tried to remember it as well as I could because I can't bring it home to work on, also they values of the scores change in the procedure.

Comment: Returning values from a function accomplishes ABSOLUTELY NOTHING if you do nothing with those values!  `return` does not make the values available with the same name they had within the function, which is what you seem to be expecting; it makes them available as the value of the function call.  Try `score1, score2 = roll(score1, score2)`.  The fact that the values have the same names inside and outside the function is just a coincidence, and a likely source of confusion here.

Comment: @jasonharper thanks I'll try that in a second.

Comment: @jasonharper thanks, that works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this fixed it:
Returning values from a function accomplishes ABSOLUTELY NOTHING if you do nothing with those values! return does not make the values available with the same name they had within the function, which is what you seem to be expecting; it makes them available as the value of the function call. Try score1, score2 = roll(score1, score2). The fact that the values have the same names inside and outside the function is just a coincidence, and a likely source of confusion here. – jasonharper